# How to retrieve the image from camera without using camera app (via a service)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I need to create a service application which always looking and retrieve imaging file from if any new image taken from build in camera application.

1)My service needs to watching and taking the image from if new image was taken from build in camera application

how can we obtain the image path or image data in my service.

Comment: I tried to edit your question as best as I understood it; but you need to clarify what you want to happen. Try updating your question with a series of step that you want the user to do. For example 1. Open my application 2. Click on camera button 2. My application shows camera view 3. User captures image using my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

manifest code:

```
 <receiver android:name=".pictureReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="10000" >
           <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE"/>
      <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

onReceive Code:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
           String selectedImageUri = arg1.getData().getPath();
           Log.d("TAG", "Received new photo:::"+selectedImageUri );
               Log.d("TAG","file Path"+getRealPathFromURI(arg1.getData(),arg0));
    }
 public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri,Context context)
        {
            try
            {
                String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor =  context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return contentUri.getPath();
            }
        }
```

Comment: apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Answer (score 1):

FYI it is recommended to listen to the official broadcast since ICS API level 14: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#ACTION_NEW_PICTURE. So filter for "android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE", and use "com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" in addition only if you need to support pre-ICS as well.